# Question about integral

Tags: analysis

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x\sin x}{4+x^2}dx.
$$
How  can  we  calculate  this  integral  by  Feynman  integration  method?

Answer (score 1):

Let for $t>0$ 
$$
F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(xt)}{4+x^2}{\rm d}x\tag 1
$$
so that 
$$
F(1)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{4+x^2}{\rm d}x\tag{$\star$}
$$
Fixing $t > 0$, set $y = xt$, so ${\rm d}y = t \,{\rm d}x$ and
$$
F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y\sin y}{4t^2+y^2}{\rm d}y\tag 2
$$
This new integral will be accessible to differentiation under the integral sign. Differentiating under the integral sign we obtain
$$
F'(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{y\sin y}{4t^2+y^2}\right){\rm d}y=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-8t\, y\sin y}{(4t^2+y^2)^2}{\rm d}y\tag 3
$$
We want to compute $F''(t)$ using differentiation under the integral sign.
We obtain
$$
F''(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\left(\frac{y\sin y}{4t^2+y^2}\right){\rm d}y=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\left(\frac{-4y}{4t^2+y^2}\right)\sin y\ {\rm d}y\tag 4
$$
and integrating by parts twice we obtain
$$
F''(t)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{-4y}{4t^2+y^2}\right)\ {\rm d}y=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{4y\sin y}{4t^2+y^2}\ {\rm d}y\tag 5
$$
that is 
$$
F''(t)=4F(t)\tag 6
$$
The equation (6) is a second order linear ODE whose general solution is 
$$
F(t)=A{\rm e}^{2t}+B{\rm e}^{-2t}\tag 7
$$
for all $t > 0$ and some real constants $A$ and $B$.

To determine $A$ and $B$ we look at the behavior as $t\to 0^+$ and as $t\to\infty$.
For $t\to 0^+$, from (2) we have
$$
F(0)=A+B=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y}{\rm d}y=\pi
$$
that is $B=\pi-A$ and the (7) becomes
$$
F(t)=A{\rm e}^{2t}+(\pi-A){\rm e}^{-2t}.
$$
For $t\to \infty$, from (1) integrating by parts we have
$$
F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(xt)}{4+x^2}{\rm d}x=\left[-\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}\frac{x}{4+x^2}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(xt)\frac{4-x^2}{(4+x^2)^2}{\rm d}x
$$
from wich we obtain 
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}F(t)=0
$$
and then $A=0$.

Finally we have
$$
F(t)=\pi{\rm e}^{-2t}\tag 8
$$
and for $t=1$ we find
$$
F(1)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{4+x^2}{\rm d}x=\frac{\pi}{{\rm e}^2}.\tag{$\star\star$}
$$

Comment: Thank thank  thank  you  very  much.  Best  explantion!!!!

Answer (score -1):

**Without Feyman (go guess the parameter that will work!), but with complex analysis**

Define

$$f(z)=\frac{ze^{iz}}{4+z^2}\;,\;\;C_R=[-R,R]\cup\gamma_R:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;z=Re^{it}\;,\;0<\le t<\pi\}\;$$

The only residue of $\;f\;$ within the domain enclosed by $\;C_R\;$ , with $\;R\;$ big enough, is $\;2i\;$ , so

$$\text{Res}_{z=2i}(f)=\lim_{z\to 2i}(z-2i)f(z)=\frac{2ie^{-2}}{4i}=\frac1{2e^2}$$

so by the Cauchy's RT

$$\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z)dz=2\pi i\frac1{2e^2}=\frac{\pi i}{e^2}$$

Now

$$\left|\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz\right|\le\pi \max_{z\in\gamma_R}\frac{|z||e^{iz}|}{|4+z^2|}\le\pi\frac{Re^{-R\sin t}}{4-R^2}\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

so

$$\frac{\pi i}{e^2}=\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z)dz=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+4}dx$$

and now just compare imaginary parts.

Comment: Who is Feyman?  Do you mean Feynman?  And you do not guess parameters, you think of how to come up with an integrand that has nice symmetry properties and is uniformly convergent. @DonAntonio